# Change number value on selection of different option in selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simply want to change values of my input type number on the selection of a different option from the select box.

I can apply if else then do this but I want a less complex and few lines code which works easily.
For eg: If I choose A, B, C then the value of input will be "A"
same if I choose a,b,c then the value of input will be "a", Basically I want their initials only in input type number.

HTML:

```
<select name="number_select" id="number_select" class="number_select div_height font_size" accesskey="n">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1, 2, 3, ...</option>
<option value="2">a, b, c, ...</option>
<option value="3">A, B, C, ...</option>
<option value="4">i, ii, iii, ...</option>
<option value="4">I, II, III, ...</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="start_number" id="start_number" class="start_number div_border font_size" value="1" min="1" max="9" accesskey="s"/>
```

Comment: So why would you use a `type="number"` if you want it's value to be a character ?

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#number_select").change(function() {
  var option = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  if ($.isNumeric( option[0] ))
    $("#start_number").attr("type", "number");
  else 
    $("#start_number").attr("type", "text");
  $("#start_number").val(option[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="number_select" id="number_select" class="number_select div_height font_size" accesskey="n">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1, 2, 3, ...</option>
<option value="2">a, b, c, ...</option>
<option value="3">A, B, C, ...</option>
<option value="4">i, ii, iii, ...</option>
<option value="4">I, II, III, ...</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="start_number" id="start_number" class="start_number div_border font_size" value="1" min="1" max="9" accesskey="s" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the code snippet and check the values in `console.log` but the values won't reflect in the `input` since you have defined its type as `number`

```js
$("#number_select").change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  console.log("Initials: " + selectedValue[0]);
  $("#start_number").val(selectedValue[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="number_select" id="number_select" class="number_select div_height font_size" accesskey="n">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1, 2, 3, ...</option>
<option value="2">a, b, c, ...</option>
<option value="3">A, B, C, ...</option>
<option value="4">i, ii, iii, ...</option>
<option value="4">I, II, III, ...</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="start_number" id="start_number" class="start_number div_border font_size" value="1" min="1" max="9" accesskey="s" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#number_select').change(() => {
    $('#start_number').val($('#number_select').val());
});
```